# When AEM is configured to use a S3 data store will it make blue-green deployments faster?

Tags: amazon-s3, aem, devops, sling, jackrabbit-oak

**Background**

We know it's possible to setup a devops pipeline that deploys updates to AEM via a blue/green approach by using crx2oak to migrate the content from old to new environment. *Why is out of scope of this question.*

The problem with this approach is the content copy operation can take a significant time, as the amount of content in the JCR grows. *Other ideas to mittigate this are appreciated.*

We also know that AEM can have a S3 datastore that off-loads the binary content into a S3 bucket which would not be re-built during blue/green deployment as per:

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/deploying/using/storage-elements-in-aem-6.html#OverviewofStorageinAEM6

What is unclear from Adobe's documentation is whether the same S3 bucket can be shared across AEM instances (i.e. blue/green instances). *Maybe it's just my google fu that has failed...*

**Question(s)**

When a new AEM instance is configured to use a S3 datastore that already has content in it from the old instance, when crx2oak is used to migrate content, will the new instance be able to access the existing content?

Are there any articles/blogs that describe what the potential time savings of this approach would be?

*Yes I could do an experiment, and may do so in the future to answer my own question. I'm looking for information from anyone who has already done this? I'm an **engineer** so will not re-invent the wheel if someone else has done so.*

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly share the same S3 bucket between instances - in fact, this is commonly used along with binary-less replication from author->publisher(s) and is a tried and true configuration.

It's even possible to share the same bucket between completely different environments (e.g. DEV/STAGE, or BLUE/GREEN in your case). The main "gotcha" to be aware of is with regard to DataStore Garbage Collection (DSGC) because it's very possible that there will be blobs which are referenced by only some of the instances sharing the bucket and so when purging unused blobs this needs to be taken into account.

This is all part of the design though, and there is a flag designed specifically for this purpose which tells DSGC to only execute the first phase (the "mark" phase) of GC, and skip the 2nd "sweep" phase, until all instances have marked which blobs they wish to keep/discard. Once all instances have done so the sweep phase can be run to purge blobs not needed by any instances using the bucket.

For a more detailed explanation see the Oak docs:
https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/plugins/blobstore.html#Shared_DataStore_Blob_Garbage_Collection_Since_1.2.0

I find it helps to understand that pretty much all of the datastore implementations are done such that blobs are stored according to their checksum, so the same file added uploaded twice  will only have one copy stored in the datastore, and there will be two segment store records referencing that same blob. In the same way, multiple AEM instances sharing the same bucket will be able to find a given blob regardless of which instance put it there in the first place.

You can observe see this in action easily with `FileDataStore` by finding a blob and `sha256`'ing it - e.g. (this example is on OS X, the checksum command on Linux/Windows will be slightly different):

```
$ shasum -a256 crx-quickstart/repository/datastore/0c/9e/40/0c9e405fc8d0f0405930cd0044611cfbf014938a1837ae0cfaa266d7732d1002

0c9e405fc8d0f0405930cd0044611cfbf014938a1837ae0cfaa266d7732d1002  crx-quickstart/repository/datastore/0c/9e/40/0c9e405fc8d0f0405930cd0044611cfbf014938a1837ae0cfaa266d7732d1002
```

There you can see that a) the filename is the checksum, and b) it's nested using the first 3 pairs of characters from that checksum, so you can locate the file by just knowing the hash and if you store the same binary, even if the name or JCR metadata is different, the blob referenced will be the same literal file on disk.

From memory S3 datastore uses prefixes rather than directory nesting because this performance better, but the principle is the same.

Finally, a couple of things to consider are:

1) S3 storage is relatively cheap (and practically unlimited) so there is an argument to be made that it's not as necessary to perform regular DSGC unless you're really trying to pinch pennies.

2) If you do run DSGC you need to think about how this will work with whatever backup strategy you're using for the AEM instances. For instance, if you roll back a segment store shortly after running DSGC you'll likely have to recover some of those purged blobs. You can use versioning and/or lifecycle rules to help with this, but it can add significant additional complexity and time to your restore process.

If you opt to simply skip DSGC and leave the blobs there indefinitely it's a good idea to make sure the access key or IAM roles AEM is using doesn't have the `DeleteObject` permission for the bucket, just to be sure a rogue GC process can't delete anything.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**
In all that I forgot to actually answer your question - yes it will save some time in cloning in most cases. You'll still need to sync the segment store (obviously) and there are various approaches for this. `crx2oak` is certainly one - you'll see in the documentation there are specific options for using it w/ S3 where you supply a configuration file (basically a serialised `.config` file like you'd use with Felix/OSGi).

You can also use something like `rsync` to simply copy the TAR files over (while at least the target AEM is stopped. Oak is generally atomic so a hot copy from the source can work in theory, but YMMV).

Finally you could obviously use Mongo and cluster the segment store that way, but all the usual cost/complexity/performance issues with doing so apply).

Another interesting development on the horizon for blue/green type is the `CompositeNodeStore` - there is a good talk from the 2017 adaptTo() conference that talks about this:

https://adapt.to/2017/en/schedule/zero-downtime-deployments-for-the-sling-based-apps-using-docker.html

Answer (score 3):

An external datastore will help a lot, as usually the most space is used by binary assets. The pure content typed in by real people is much less.

On my current project (quite small, but relations should be normal):

- Repository 4,8 GB total (4.1 GB Segment Store, 780 MB Index)
- File DataStore 222 GB total

If you wanna do it, I have the following remarks:

1. There are different datastores available. For testing I would start with the **File DataStore**.
2. The **S3 DataStore** makes only sense in my point of view, if you are hosting at Amazons AWS anyway. Adobe Managed Services is doing this, and so S3 makes sense for them. But also there only if you have more than 500 GB assets.
3. If you use the green/blue approach, then be careful the DataStore garbage collection (just do it manually). The shared Datastore is meant for several publishers, that have the same content. As example you could have the following situation: Your editors delete some assets, you run the DataStore GC and finally your rollback your environment. That means the assets are still in the content repository, but the binaries are cleaned out of the DataStore.

---

In order to to use a shared file datastore, you need to do the following:

1. Unpack Quickstart `java -jar AEM_6.3_Quickstart.jar -unpack`
2. Create an directory for the file datastore (anywhere outside of the crx-quickstart folder)
3. Create a directory `install` inside the extracted `crx-quickstart` folder
4. Create a file called `org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.blob.datastore.FileDataStore.cfg` inside this install folder
5. This file contains just 1 line `path=<path to file datastore>` (see https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/osgi_config.html)
6. Place a `reference.key` file inside the datastore directory. First time it will be created automatically. But if you use always the same key, the same hash-values are used all datastores across all your environments. This is  also a prerequisite for a feature called "binary-less replication" (so binary would only be replicated the first time between author and publisher)

kind regards,
Alex